# Andengine Game null pointer exception while trying to show winner's facebook profile pic

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, andengine

I am working on an andngine game in which i am trying to show profile pic of level winner using facebok graph api i am using following code

```
try {
    Texture itexture= new BitmapTexture(engine.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

        @Override
        public InputStream open() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            URL url = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+userId+"/picture?type=square");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input);    
            return in;
        }
    });
    itexture.load();
    TextureRegion MyImageFromWeb=TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(itexture);
    Sprite img=new Sprite(550, 400,MyImageFromWeb, vbom);
    attachChild(img);
    attachChild(new Text(550, 450, resourcesManager.font, name, vbom));
} catch (IOException e) {
    Debug.e(e);
} catch (FacebookError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

initially this code was working fine but from past two day's i am getting Null Pointer Exception when winner image is fetched from facebook ,my log is as following

> 03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1359
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531): org.andengine.util.exception.NullBitmapException: Caused by: 'org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture@413e72a8'.
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTexture.java:107)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:145)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:268)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:633)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1516)
>   03-31 19:22:27.325: E/AndroidRuntime(18531):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)

Hoping for quick reply from someone ,Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto redirection works automatically when original and redirected protocols are same.

So, try to load images from **https** instead of **http** : "https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture"; since actual image's url is "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/...."